# Почему не работает правило CSS?

Tags: css, css3

```
.notifications .left-notif-wrap ul li:hover>.close {
    display:block;
}
```

Для такой структуры:

```
<div class="notifications">
    <div class="left-notif-wrap">
        <ul> 
          <li><span>Close</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нет элемента с классом `.close`.

Comment: Элемент таков есть

Comment: Элемент span есть, если ві его блочным хотите сделать, то правило должно быть 
.notifications .left-notif-wrap ul li:hover>span{...}

Comment: у вас а html нет элемента с классом `close`, у спана нет этого класса: `<li><span>Close</span></li>`.

Comment: для тоого чтобы заработал код вам нужно будет написать: `<li><span class="close">Close</span></li>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hkcnvgm0/

Answer (score 1):

В вашем комбинаторе потомков указан только класс `.close` (кстати где он?), а нужно ещё указать сам элемент. Для того чтобы текст "Close" при наведении курсора становился блочным элементом, попробуйте вот это:

```
.notifications .left-notif-wrap ul li:hover>span {display:block;}
```